# Inline Datatables editable for .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, datatables

How i can use datatables editable from [this example](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/simple) in my .net core project. 
Can't understand how i can call transfer data by ajax in my controller. 
For example i have method

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SaveWorkPageData()
{
    var m = //want to get data from request in this veriable
   return Json();
}
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Search(string orderBy, List<Order> order, Search search,
        int start, int length, string searchTerm, bool isAsc, bool hideVoidedAndDeclined, bool recent = false)
    {
        var take = length;
        var skip = start;
        var m = _clientsService.Search(searchTerm, orderBy, hideVoidedAndDeclined, isAsc, take, skip, recent);


        return Json(m);
    }
```

JS code:

```
function ClientSearchGridBase() {

var self = {};
self.parentContainerSelector = ".client-search-grid";
self.searchUrl = "/Clients/Search";
self.saveDataUrl = "/Clients/SaveWorkPageData";
var editor;
self.init = function () {
    editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor({
        "ajax": {
            "url": self.saveDataUrl,
            "type": "POST",
            "dataSrc": function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                return response;
            }

        },
        table: self.parentContainerSelector + ' table',
        fields: [{
                label: "PKID:",
                name: "PKID"
            }, {
                label: "Last name:",
                name: "Name"
            }
        ]
    });

    $(self.parentContainerSelector + ' table').on('click', 'tbody td', function (e) {
        editor.inline(this);
    });

    self.table = $(self.parentContainerSelector + ' table').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "pageLength": 10,
        "ajax": {
            "url": self.searchUrl,
            "type": "POST",
            data: function (data) {
                data.orderBy = data.columns[data.order[0].column].data;
                data.searchTerm = data.search.value;
                data.isAsc = data.order[0].dir == "asc";
                data.hideVoidedAndDeclined = $(self.parentContainerSelector + " .hide-voided-and-declined").is(":checked");
            }
        },
        idSrc: 'PKID',
        "columns": [
            {
                "data": "PKID"
            },
            {
                "data": "Name"
            }
        ],
        order: [
            [1, "desc"]
        ],
        buttons: [
            { extend: "create", editor: editor },
            { extend: "edit", editor: editor },
            { extend: "remove", editor: editor }
        ]
    }).rows().ids();

    $(document.body).on("click", self.parentContainerSelector + " td:first-of-type .edit", self.edit);
    $(document.body).on("change", self.parentContainerSelector + " .hide-voided-and-declined", self.hideVoidedAndDeclined);

    self.table.on('xhr', function (e, settings, json) {
        console.log('Ajax event occurred. Returned data: ', json);
    });
}


self.hideVoidedAndDeclined = function () {
    self.table.draw();
}

self.edit = function (event) {
    var rowIndex = $(event.target).closest("tr").index();
    var itemId = self.table.row(rowIndex).data().QuoteId;
    location.href = "/Quotes/Manage/" + itemId;

}

return self;

}
```

How i need to change`SaveWorkPageData` method for work with data?

Comment: do you want to get response data of your ajax request? `ajax: "client/SaveWorkPageData" `

Comment: yes. i want to get response data

Comment: Added example in answer, let me know!

Answer (score 0):

On the client side you want to declare editor and then activate it:

```
var editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor({
        ajax: '@Url.Action("ProductOutputList")',
        table: '#productoutputs',
        fields: [
            {
                "label": "Name:",
                "name": "productoutputs.Name"
            }], //more fields
        formOptions: {
            inline: {
                onBlur: 'submit'
            }
        }
    });
    // Activate an inline edit on click of a table cell
    $('#productoutputs').on('click', 'tbody td.editable', function (e) {
        editor.inline(this);
    });
```

On the server side you want to process the request. So, the data is being transferred to your controller and you can process it with editor plugin (the documentation is here https://editor.datatables.net/manual/net/):

```
public ActionResult ProductOutputList()
    {
        var request = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request;
        var settings = Properties.Settings.Default;

        using (var db = new Database(settings.DbType, settings.DbConnection))
        {
            var response = new Editor(db, "productoutputs", "ProductOutputId")
                .Model<ProductOutputDatatablesModel>()
                .Field(new Field("productoutputs.ProductId")
                    .Options("products", "ProductId", "Name")
                )
                .LeftJoin("products", "products.ProductId", "=", "productoutputs.ProductId")
                .Field(new Field("productoutputs.DesignId")
                    .Options("designs", "DesignId", "Name")
                )
                .Process(request)
                .Data();

            return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Also you want to create settings for your database connection:
[settings file screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYxgM.png)

Comment: I try to do this. but cant because i think its using just for asp.net mvc. And me using .net core